# Combine 2 rows in 1 duplicating the values in r

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-manipulation

i have this data

```
data.frame(start_date =as.Date(c('2020-03-02', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-16')),
           end_date =as.Date(c('2020-03-06', '2020-03-13', '2002-03-20')),
           a = c(9, 1, 8),
           b = c(6, 5, 7))
```

and I want to manipulate it to transform it like this

```
data.frame(date =as.Date(c('2020-03-02', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-06', '2020-03-13', '2002-03-20')),
           a = c(9, 1, 8, 9, 1, 8),
           b = c(6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 7))
```

How can i do it? Thanks!

Comment: Use `df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = start_date:end_date, values_to = 'date') %>% select(-name)`

Comment: AAAAAAAAAHHHH! THANKSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tidyr gather function to get this.

-First assign the data frame as an object.

-Then, gather the start and end dates with their a and b values respectively. (by excluding a and b from gather with a minus "-" sign.) Change the name of the value column with "date". The output from the gather was like that.

```
df %>%
  gather(key, value = "date", -a, -b)
          a b        key       date
        1 9 6 start_date 2020-03-02
        2 1 5 start_date 2020-03-09
        3 8 7 start_date 2020-03-16
        4 9 6   end_date 2020-03-06
        5 1 5   end_date 2020-03-13
        6 8 7   end_date 2002-03-20
```

-For the last part, in order to get rid of the "key" column (start_date and end_date), select only the ones you wanted.

See the full code below:

```
df <- data.frame(start_date =as.Date(c('2020-03-02', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-16')),
           end_date =as.Date(c('2020-03-06', '2020-03-13', '2002-03-20')),
           a = c(9, 1, 8),
           b = c(6, 5, 7)) #df assignment to an object

df1 <- df %>%
  gather(key, value = "date", -a, -b) %>% #gathering dates
  select(date, a, b) #choosing what is needed
```

-This full code brings this output:

```
        date a b
1 2020-03-02 9 6
2 2020-03-09 1 5
3 2020-03-16 8 7
4 2020-03-06 9 6
5 2020-03-13 1 5
6 2002-03-20 8 7
```